# This powershell script is not working Can anybody help me?

Tags: powershell, automation, dns

My Scenario is
I have 2 subnets 172.16.48.0 and 172.16.58.0
I need to change the DNS to .1
Now there are a few more subnets but I don't want any change in other subnets so the script/batch file need to check the IP address of the client and then assign a DNS address

Please lookinto the following script it's not working:

```
        Get-NetAdapter | where status -eq up
        if($wmi.ipaddress -ne "172.16.48.*")
                {$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("172.16.48.1")}
 
 
        if($wmi.ipaddress -ne "172.16.58.*")
                            {$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("172.16.58.1")}
        Or
        Get-NetAdapter | where status -eq up
        if($wmi.ipaddress -eq "172.16.48.*")
                {$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("172.16.48.1")}
 
 
        elseif($wmi.ipaddress -eq "172.16.58.*")
                            {$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("172.16.58.1")}
 
        else {
        exit}
```

Comment: Try `-Like` when using wild cards

Comment: Where is variable `$wmi` defined?

Comment: why are you running `Get-NetAdapter` and not using it?

Comment: I'm new to powershell, kindly help me in correcting the script